# 'man' in genitive condition?

Tags: word-choice

when someone gives a general rule, the pronoun 'man' is used, for example:

> "wenn man Gemüse kauft, sollte man sicherstellen, dass es frisch ist."
>
> = "when you buy vegetables, you need to make sure that they're fresh."

But if I need to say the following:

> "When your friends are in trouble, you should help them."

Should I use 'jemandes'? Or should I just invert the positions of the clauses, like:

> Man sollte seinen Freunden helfen, wenn sie in Schwierigkeiten sind.

?

Comment: *Man sollte seinen Freunden helfen...* is entirely fine, even if none of the answers mention this..

Comment: BTW, you question is about the possesive pronoun, not the genitive. For cases other than the nominative, you replace "man" with "einer", just like English "one". See e.g. [canoo](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-man.html?lang=en)

Comment: could you please give an answer with an example?

Answer (score 3):

The solution you gave with inverting the positions sounds good. Using "jemandes" would sound rather strange. If you want the original order, I would either translate the English version, so say

> Wenn deine Freunde in Schwierigkeiten sind, solltest du ihnen helfen.

or drop the pronoun all together, i.e. saying

> Freunden in Not hilft man.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, "man" is not the same as "you(r)" - it's rather the equivalent to using "one(s)".

Example: "When one's friends are in trouble, one should help them."

But concerning your question: The second example sounds pretty good. Avoid using "jemandes", it sounds totally weird & there's a better formulation in 99% of all situations.